# recompile nginx with build name and preserve current configurations

Tags: nginx, security

So I've been running nginx servers for while and I've made a nice bunch of changes to get it just right for one of my clients. They have recently employed pen testers and want me to harden security. As such I need to hide the build name of nginx to meet their requirements. However it seems I need to recompile nginx to do that. I just wondering if there's a way to keep all my changes to config etc when recompiling with the build name option.

Comment: There is no reason to recompile nginx for anything. Exactly what is the "requirement" that they gave you? Quote it verbatim; copy and paste it.

Comment: I need to mask what webserver is running, so besides just hiding the version number they want me to make it so someone looking at the site can't tell it's nginx. I thought I had to have nginx compiled with the --build-name option to be able to do that. Is there another one to enable the ability to change the name from nginx?

Comment: That doesn't look like something that would appear on a penetration test report.

Comment: And yet here I am? They want it hidden so I'ma hide it if I can

Comment: I asked you a simple question and you ignored it. Please don't do that. First, it's rude. Second, we're trying to actually help you here.

Comment: They said to hide the webserver, and included a picture of wappalyzer and an arrow pointed at nginx. I replied to you pretty detailed explaining what the goal was and you told me that isn't what they would report. Who's being rude here?

Comment: Your question seems straightforward. Yes you need to include headers-more to set headers. Whether you compile Nginx or use a version from a repository that already includes it is up to you. Building Nginx is simple, I have a [guide here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/upgrade-running-nginx-amazon-linux/).

Comment: I was forced to revert your edit. Answers belong in the answers below, not as edits to the question where they will be either missed or misinterpreted. Please feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: Ah yes people googling it hate when the answer is right below the question. My mistake I will place it further down the page as requested.

Comment: @Michael Hampton I've certainly seen it on PCI-DSS reports and it may depend on the strictness of the scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer I needed from this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594971/how-to-changehide-the-nginx-server-signature/38967105#38967105

> If you are working in ubuntu then
>
> First install nginx-extras

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

> Go to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and under http add:

```
http {
    more_set_headers "Server: Your_New_Server_Name";
    server_tokens off; 
}
```

> Restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configurations won't change when nginx is rebuilt. If `make install` detects existing configurations it doesn't overwrite them. To be entirely sure, just copy `nginx.conf` to `nginx.conf.bak` or similar. However, it sounds like you need configuration management and some kind of build process, which will give you extra points with a security audit. I would consider at least setting up a local `git` repository for your configurations, and possibly `travis` or `jenkins` to manage releases as you will need to keep on top of new security updates.

For any searches reaching here, the nginx version is set at compilation time by the `NGINX_VER` variable, but don't change it globally as other processes use that. The variable needs to be changed manually in `ngx_http_header_filter_module.c` in the following locations:

```
static u_char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: yourservername" CRLF;
static u_char ngx_http_server_full_string[] = "Server: yourservername/1.0" CRLF;
static u_char ngx_http_server_build_string[] = "Server: " NGINX_VER_BUILD CRLF;
```

Comment: So this seemed like it should work and it might for other people however for some reason after running through ./configure, make, make install curl -i http://localhost/ was still returning nginx. 

What ended up working for me was this comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38967105/1467850

Comment: I've learned from tims guide that I need to run make upgrade and make clean aswell that might be why my recompiled version didn't work. However as I've now got nginx-extras working I think I will leave it as is.